# How do I associate data with a SignalR connection in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

In my old SignalR (pre-Core) project, I used to have a `static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyConnectionClass> Connections = new ...;` to represent my individual connections with additional data acquired during the connection life time.

How do I solve this in SignalR for .NET Core?

I am looking at this manual: https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/recap-creating-a-demo-of-real-time-communication-app-using-aspnetcore-signalr-d8ac0afba081

which uses the following:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<HubConnectionContext, UserDetails> _usersOnline;
```

Now, I'm wondering if I should use the HubConnectionContext as a key. Is it safe to use? Will that instance always be associated with the connection id for as long as the connection is viable? I'm not using load balancing of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I'm wondering if I should use the HubConnectionContext as a key. Is it safe to use? Will that instance always be associated with the connection id for as long as the connection is viable?

No. The implementation described by that article actually uses:

1. [`ConcurrentDictionary<string, UserDetailsDto>`](https://github.com/AndrejsAbrickis/PlanningPoker/blob/cc76c460eb5f904b1afd9649e6ecc2fb8e3ba542/PlanningPoker.Core/InMemoryUserTracker.cs#L12)
2. [`_userTracker.AddUser(connection.ConnectionId, new UserDetailsDto (...))`](https://github.com/AndrejsAbrickis/PlanningPoker/blob/4d106ec4f0c0e4c1d403518c4cece2e7bfc82d24/PlanningPoker.Core/PresenceHubLifetimeManager.cs#L50)

`connection.ConnectionId` is safe to use and sufficient to associate data with the connection.